# As I cannot Adding an xml layout below a dynamic sized canvas

Tags: java, android, xml, android-canvas, screen-size

I am looking to implement a xml layout below my canvas, my canvas is a square block which baries in size depending on the width of the phone (detects width and matches height).

My app is always displayed in portrait mode and therefore this leaves a gap underneath my canvas. Due to all the various screen sizes this space under the canvas is constantly changing. Within this section I would like to add a layout, allowing me to add textviews and a couple of image buttons. I am currently doing this all within onDraw however this is very messy code and means I have 3 variations of the code due to the vast size differences between screens.

I currently have a Game class, which in turn calls the GameView which consists of all the onDraw code, the question is how can I add a layout to fill whatever space is left under the canvas? Please see below for a basic breakdown of the Game/ GameView classes:

GAME CLASS

```
public class Game extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        this.maze = (Maze)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if(this.maze == null) 
        {
            this.maze = (Maze)extras.get("maze");
        }

        // This is where I am setting the view, this leads to my onDraw code which progromatically creates as maze.
        // This is a square box taking the width of the screen as the dimensions for the square.
        GameView view = (GameView)findViewById(R.id.gameview);
        view.setMaze(this.maze);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

GAMEVIEW CLASS - With a small snippet of the manually created text content under the canvas

```
public class GameView extends View
{
    // This is the second canvas within the maze, which sites below the main game maze which is the square i mentioned previously.
    // This is where i need to add a layout which dynamically fills any remaining space.
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        // Setting the canvas size for previous calcuated values.
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, background);
        if((PhoneWidth < PhoneHeight) && (PhoneWidth < 600))
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(arrows, QTRWidth * 2, height + 50, null);

            if(CharacterCount >= 3)
            {
                canvas.drawText(Characters.get(2).Name(), 10, height + 135, GrayTextMedium);
                // HIT POINTS
                if((float)Characters.get(2).HitPoints() / (float)Characters.get(2).HitPointsMax() < 0.11)
                    canvas.drawText("HP: " + Characters.get(2).HitPoints(), 10, height + 160, RedTextMedium);
                else
                    canvas.drawText("HP: " + Characters.get(2).HitPoints(), 10, height + 160, GrayTextMedium);
                // MAGIC POINTS
                if((float)Characters.get(0).MagicPoints() / (float)Characters.get(0).MagicPointsMax() < 0.11)
                    canvas.drawText("MP: " + Characters.get(2).MagicPoints(), QTRWidth, height + 160, RedTextMedium);
                else
                    canvas.drawText("MP: " + Characters.get(2).MagicPoints(), QTRWidth, height + 160, GrayTextMedium);
            }
            if(CharacterCount == 1) { canvas.drawText("MONEY: " + Characters.get(0).Money(), 10, height + 80, GrayTextMedium); }
            if(CharacterCount == 2) { canvas.drawText("MONEY: " + Characters.get(0).Money(), 10, height + 135, GrayTextMedium); }
            if(CharacterCount == 3) { canvas.drawText("MONEY: " + Characters.get(0).Money(), 10, height + 190, GrayTextMedium); }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me clean up this code, or point me to a detailed tutorial elsewhere. I have been looking into this and trying various things to no avail, therefore any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As the `GameView` is a square(so you're overriding `onMeasure()`) what's stopping you from wrapping it in a layout and putting whatever views you want at the bottom?

Comment: I am fairly new to Android development and not really sure how to do this, could you give me an example layout and how to call it within my Game class.

Comment: Thr game class then calls my MazeCreator class, which draws a maze within the canvas and onDraw ads various bitmaps on top of that? Some example would be very helpful as I am currenty a little lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am looking to implement a xml layout below my canvas, my canvas is a
>   square block which baries in size depending on the width of the phone
>   (detects width and matches height).

Then wrap the `GameView` in another layout and put whatever you want below that(use this layout in the `Game` activity):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <your.GameView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Assuming that your current `GameView` properly overrides the `onMeasure()` method to make itself a square then the `RelativeLayout` will get all the leftover space, where you could put the extra views.

> Due to all the various screen sizes this space under the canvas is
>   constantly changing. Within this section I would like to add a layout,
>   allowing me to add textviews and a couple of image buttons.

Do you plan to add extra views based on the space available(for example if the height is bigger then x then also add a `TextView` or something like this on top of some buttons?)? If yes, then make your own layout for that gap and in the `onMeasure()` method of that custom layout see the available space and use only the views that fit in that space.

Comment: I do not override the onMeasure at any stage, I simply assign the size of the canvas by doing calculating the width of the screen using display metrics

Comment: @LandLPartners Use this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/6240480 in your `GameView`. This will make the view a square(so there's no need for a canvas resizing). Then you'll have space in the layout I posted(use vertical orientation for the LinearLayout) to add the extra views.

Comment: I have amended my orginal code, for the onDraw, not sure where I need to add onMeasure and how to implement it into my current setup without re-coding everything.

Comment: If it is easier to understand my problem. I can provide you with a more complete chunk of my code?

Comment: @LandLPartners The `onMeasure()` it's a callback for any `View` class so just copy it the method in your `GameView` class. By adding that method the `GameView` will be a square so you don't need to  make that if test(PhoneWidth < PhoneHeight...) in the `onDraw()` method. Then you could move the buttons or whatever you're drawing there outside of the `GameView` in the space available at the bottom.

Comment: What should i be assigning to unbound_size as this is giving me a error ... also have pasted some more detailed version of my code here - http://pastebin.com/C183bsYW - It contains 3 classes - game.java and gameview.java then mazecreator.java?

Comment: @LandLPartners Sorry about that, the `UNBOUND_SIZE` is an arbitrary value, I used 800.

Comment: Got the onMeasure() code to work, the final part of this is how would I add the layout (Game.java page, within onCreate?). Also, how can i get my layout to use up all and only the remaning space (your code above)? Thanks

Comment: @LandLPartners Then either use the layout from my answer or build in code the layout and set it as the content view of the Activity(instead of the `GameView`). Then you'll have at the bottom the space to move some views representing what you currently draw in that if condition in the `onDraw` method for the `GameView`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35520/discussion-between-landl-partners-and-luksprog)

Comment: I have virtually implemented everything I was after, the only issue I am now having is linking the layout buttons etc to the gameview. Thanks

Comment: @LandLPartners That shouldn't be too hard to do. You'll need to set the listeners on the extra views and in those listeners call methods on your `GameView`. For example if you have a view for moving something in the `GameView`, then set a listener on that view and in the listener call a method on the `GameView` and set the new state(and in that method also call `invalidate()` so the `GameView` is forced to redrawn itself with the new state).

Comment: Hi, I tried implmenting onclicklisteners, however could not get it to link up to my onDraw/ 3rd java class (this is what handles the position pf the user within the maze). I need the onclick listeners to be linked to the gameview, if you could provide some sample code that would really help.

Comment: @LandLPartners I think you're approaching this the wrong way. The views in the layout at the bottom should only post update on the GameView(like modifying some variables, changing positions etc and then let the view to update itself) and not interact directly with the `onDraw` method of the GameView. Here's a very basic GameView example on how you might do the interaction between the views: https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/c08924ff66666e083ec574c7e320fc2aad8ed8b8/src/com/luksprog/playground/view/GameViewSample.java

Comment: I currently am doing it in a very similar way to your example. I also, have the button detecting as they should etc. The only issue is the way I call my move function was previously donw with ontouch, I am missing something here to implement this into my onclick buttons? http://pastebin.com/SZzZKkyZ

Comment: @LandLPartners In that move method you should also call the `invalidate()` method to let the view know that it needs a redraw.

Comment: I undertstand the principal that i need to add invalidate(), however not sure where in my code I need to add it as my move function is not within the game or gameview java, it is a 3rd external java class. Also, I am no longer using onTouch within my View class as is no longer valid

Comment: @LandLPartners If you update that external class and with data that has the potential of changing how the view looks then call invalidate after every time calling move: `switch (v.getId()) {
                                case R.id.btnUp:
                                      maze.move(Maze.UP); gameView.invalidate();
                                break;.....`

Comment: I was accidently calling invalidate on the layout view instead of the gameview. This is all working correctly, thanks for your help.